# Work Around for Ghost Inspector 10-min Test Limit

Tags: html, testing, automation, ui-automation, ghost-inspector

I'm having a difficult time trying to find a work-around for the 10 minute Test Maximum on Ghost Inspector.

> FYI: Ghost Inspector is an codeless Automation Tool that can create, manage
> and execute browsers tests. Ensure your website is working properly.

So, if your test on the website exceeds 10 minutes, it will automatically stop.  The limit is advertised but I figured someone has had questions about this limit in the past.

[image]

After some research, I cannot seem to find ways to work around this.  I'm curious to finding a work-around and I've labeled some ways I thought of below.  *I'm new-ish to Ghost Inspector but have a firm grasp on how to use the tool.*

**Background**:

You can think of the test I'm doing as a household screening. You're inputting your the household info in every tab on this site (Household members (ages, dob's etc), Income, Expenses etc). Unfortunately, you can not start a test in the middle of the screening, it will have to be the beginning.  That's my dilemma.

**Scenario**:

For example, say I have household screening with 7 different tabs.  Each tab has a lot of information about all members of that household to input.  However, a user must start at the first tab `1` (see below), you can not start at 3 because the information on the prior tabs are needed. Currently, my tests are stopping by the 3rd tab because that's about when the 10 minute limit is up.

```
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7
```

So far, I've thought of the following:

> 1. In Ghost Inspector (GI), you're able to import other tests you've done and use them on a new test, however even if you import other tests, the cumulated time remains, must be under 10 min. Diagram below

```
Import 1  |
Import 2  |-- Cumulated Time (10 Min)
Import 3  |
```

**Note**:  The import tests are in order and can't be rearrange or even combined.  It would still have to be below the 10 minute max.

> 2. I've thought of doing API hit to GI but that will only start the test or suite.  Doing multiple API hits to different tests wouldn't work because that have to go in succession.

There are no additional features that let you go above the 10 minute Max.  My organization pays for Ghost Inspector so it's what we have for testing at this moment.  Any insight will be helpful and can answer any questions in the comments.

Comment: Hi William, any news on this? Did you find something to get it going anyways despite the restriction? We are facing the same issue and already optimized things a lot to get below the 10 minute mark. But with lots of e-mails to be awaited, and only being able to continue when they arrive we spend most of the time waiting, which easily eats up the 10 minutes limit. I wish Ghost Inspector would allow this value to be overridden and only default to 10 minutes if not told otherwise.

Comment: Hey @Yeehaw, Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find that much of a work around regarding this issue.  The best we could do, which was able to save just a small fraction of time on our my long tests, is to use full xpaths for our web based tests instead of Elements.  I'd love GI to change this limit and it's something I've formally discussed with them but with not much progress.